# How do you turn off memory on a Mac?

Tags: macos, memory, macbook

I have 16GB RAM on my Mac.  Instead of physically removing it, is there a software setting where I can make it think it only has 8GB RAM?

I would like to understand performance of my application with less RAM.

Comment: You could just allocate part of the memory for something else, a ramdisk perhaps. Then fill that up until you only have a certain amount of left that you want to use for testing whatever software it is you want to test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `maxmem` boot argument to the desired memory limit in MebiBytes, and then reboot.

First, see what boot arguments you already have:

```
nvram boot-args
```

Then, assuming you don't have any (this is probably the default), just add the `maxmem` boot-arg. Here's how to set it for 8GiB:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="maxmem=8192"
```

…then reboot.

You can delete the `boot-args` boot-time environment variable later like this:

```
sudo nvram -d boot-args
```

Comment: don't you need `nvram -p` to read existing params? I get an error on `nvram boot -args` ... nvram: Error getting variable - 'boot': (iokit/common) data was not found

Comment: @Tetsujin No, you don't need `-p` to read existing variables. You *do* need to correctly type the name of the variable you want to read, which in this case is `boot-args`, not `boot` or `-args`. The message you saw was what you get when the variable you asked for does not exist.

Comment: I'm copy/pasting the first [code] line of your answer - it no werky ;) Actually same response with or without the space [10.10.5 if that's relevant]

Answer (score -1):

Create a virtual machine for testing, using VMware Fusion, Parallels, or VirtualBox. This would allow you to change the amount of memory, number of CPUs, network settings, video settings, software dependencies, operating systems, etc. You can change machine settings and reboot the virtual machine, without making any changes to your host computer.